# Fdisk outputting seemingly absurd CHS values

Tags: partitioning, mbr, fdisk

Take the following fdisk input:

```
o # Create DOS/MBR partition table.
n # Create new partition.
    p # Partition type
    1 # Partition ID
    2048 # Starting sector
    +4M # Ending sector
t # Assign said partition to a FAT12 filesystem.
    1 # FAT12 filesystem.
a # Mark said partition as bootable.
w # Write partition table.
```

Now, let's take a look at the MBR, specifically of the partition entry (partition entry starts at `0x80` near the end of the first line).

```
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4a2f 9087 0000 8020  ........J/.....
000001c0: 2100 01a2 2200 0008 0000 0020 0000 0000  !..."...... ....
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa  ..............U.
```

According to the layout of the MBR portion entries (given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries) and [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Partition_Table#MBR)), the values we can glean the CHS tuple from are `0x20`, `0x21`, `0x00`.

`0x20` is rather simple: it equates to the 32nd head.

`0x21` contains both the starting sector and the starting cylinder. `0x21` -> `0b00100001`, giving `33` as the sector, and the 8th and the 9th bits of the cylinder resulting in `0` (`0b00`).

Combining the cylinder bits of `0b00` (from the `0x21`) and `0b00000000`, we get `0b0000000000` as the cylinder. All in all, we end up with a starting head of **32**, a starting sector of **33**, and a starting cylinder of **0**.

When I try and load this CHS via BIOS interrupts, it complains that the CHS is invalid (I can read other sectors just fine). I assume this is because the head is 32; after all, why would you have a 16-platter hard disk?

**tl;dr**

Fdisk outputs MBR with CHS values.

My question is if I'm misunderstanding how the CHS value is encoded into the partition entry or if this is a quirk of fdisk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to fdisk itself, the C/H/S values are indeed supposed to be:

```
Command (m for help): x

Expert command (m for help): p

Disk test.disk: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd771f127

Device     Boot Start   End Sectors Id Type  Start-C/H/S End-C/H/S Attrs
test.disk1 *     2048 10239    8192  1 FAT12     0/32/33  0/162/34    80
```

fdisk doesn't try to match the actual disk geometry – this has long been impossible within the C/H/S limits, so all it does is compute some values that would give the correct result when converted back to LBA.

Code from util-linux `include/pt-mbr.h`:

```c
static inline void
dos_partition_sync_chs(struct dos_partition *p,
                       unsigned long long int part_offset,
                       unsigned int geom_sectors,
                       unsigned int geom_heads)
{
        unsigned long long int start = part_offset + dos_partition_get_start(p);
        unsigned long long int stop = start + dos_partition_get_size(p) - 1;
        unsigned int spc = geom_heads * geom_sectors;

        if (start / spc > 1023)
                start = spc * 1024 - 1;
        if (stop / spc > 1023)
                stop = spc * 1024 - 1;

        p->bc = (start / spc) & 0xff;
        p->bh = (start / geom_sectors) % geom_heads;
        p->bs = ((start % geom_sectors + 1) & 0x3f) |
                (((start / spc) >> 2) & 0xc0);

        p->ec = (stop / spc) & 0xff;
        p->eh = (stop / geom_sectors) % geom_heads;
        p->es = ((stop % geom_sectors + 1) & 0x3f) |
                (((stop / spc) >> 2) & 0xc0);
}
```

Comment from util-linux `libfdisk/src/dos.c`:

```c
 /*
  * Conversion from C/H/S to LBA is defined by formula:
  *   LBA = (c * N_heads + h) * N_sectors + (s - 1)
  * Let o to be:
  *   o = LBA - (s - 1)
  * Then formula can be expressed as:
  *   o = (c * N_heads + h) * N_sectors
  */
```

> why would you have a 16-platter hard disk?

You *pretend* to have a 16-platter hard disk in order to represent more disk space than the C/H/S system could normally represent. With only 64ki cylinders × 255 sectors × 2 heads per platter, all you can reach is ~8 GB per platter and obviously disks have slightly outgrown that by now.

The OS or firmware doesn't control each head individually, it just passes the numbers to the disk via ATA commands and gets data back, so it doesn't really *care* whether the disk somehow has 255 heads or not. And neither does the disk itself, anymore – the first thing disks now do is use a formula to convert the C/H/S values to linear LBA addresses (assuming the disk was given C/H/S and not LBA to begin with).

So even before BIOSes and OSes switched to dealing directly with LBA, it was already common to use "absurd" C/H/S values in order to access more disk space that the format would normally allow.

All current operating systems just ignore the C/H/S fields in MBRs and deal with LBA exclusively, and apparently that's what "OnTrack Disk Manager" [used to do](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8814/566) in MS-DOS. (Also, as far as I know, SCSI disks never supported C/H/S to begin with, they were always LBA-only.) I'm somewhat sure that just about any BIOS you'll find these days has native support for LBA via "extended INT 13h" (as Google tells me).

Comment: Ah, thank you, this is precisely what I needed. I was trying with LBA, but this is sadly impossible due to restrictions. Would give you an upvote if I could :)

Comment: "*the first thing disks now do is use a formula to convert the C/H/S values to linear LBA addresses*" -- HDDs of the past 2 decades use an ATA command set that stopped using C/H/S, and only accept an LBA to specify the sector address.

Comment: By the time IDE was well-established nothing was using real geometry in CHS mode anyway, because it was more cost-effective to have a variable number of sectors per track. So they had to translate anyhow, and might as well use xxx/16/255 (for compatibility with BIOS that disbelieve in >16 heads) or xxx/63/255 (for larger capacities).